# Products incorrectly shown as out of stock - Magento 2.2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product, stock, out-of-stock

I have made a configurable product, with 4 associated configurations.

My issue is that the product configurations are set with the right quantities, by the size of the product. But the product is displayed as out of stock in the front end.

The product in question is the bottom one in the image below.

[image]

The General settings of this product is configured as in the image below.

[image]

And the different product configurations are shown below.

[image]

Now, I've noticed the obvious - that quantity is set to 0 in the general section of the product. But this is expected with Configurable products, right? Because I do need to set quantities per size, not for the product in general.

So I've been sort of banging my head against the wall for a few days trying to sort this out and I'm hoping there might be some assistance here.

I've restarted the server, reindexed the site and flushed the cache with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same problem with 2.2.1.

Somehow all the Virtual Products belonging to my Configurable product were set as "Out of Stock". I went to one of them and changed the Stock Status to "In Stock", the configurable product also became "In Stock".

An efficient way of updating Stock Status of all the Virtual Products is to search by your Configurable product name and select type as "Virtual Product". Then select all and "Update attributes", then go to "Advanced Inventory" and change the Stock Status to "In Stock" for all of them at once.

UPDATE: After spending more time creating Configurable Products on 2.2.1, I came to know that this problem occurs when you create configurations on a product that is currently "Out of Stock". Common scenario is saving a product without entering quantity and then creating Configurations on that "Out of Stock" product. This will result in all its children products to be "Out of Stock" regardless of their quantities.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that soon and hopefully the solution will be the same for Configurable & Simple products.